# prove that A does not generate the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, borel-measures

Let's say $A=\{[-a,2a]\mid a\in[0,\infty)\}$.
I want to prove that it doesn't generate the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have no idea how to start this prove because I thought it would produce the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

Can someone explain why it's not and how to start a prove like this.

Comment: Well... for instance, $\mathbb{R}\not\in A$.

Comment: Or do you mean to ask why $A$ does not generate the Borel-Algebra?

Comment: yes i mean why a does not generate the borel algebra

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant what @WoolierThanThou commented:

Your generating sets have a certain sort of "symmetry", using the term "symmetry" a bit loosely.

1. Find a clever bijective map $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that expresses that symmetry, i.e. preserves every element of $A$, ($f([-a,2a]) = [-a, 2a]$ for $a \ge 0$), but doesn't preserve many others.
2. Show that this property extends to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$.
3. Show that there is at least one set in the standard Borel $\sigma$-algebra that isn't preserved by $f$.

If you're having trouble coming up with an appropriate $f$,

> think of what you could use for $f$ if your generating sets looked like $[-a,a]$, and modify that one slightly.

---

Update (10 Jan 2024) Having done most of what was outlined above on a different post, I figured I should update this one with the details and a link to the other post.

Consider the map $\beta: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by

$$
\beta(x) =
\begin{cases}
-2x,  & \text{if $x \lt 0$} \\
-x/2, & \text{if $x \ge 0$}
\end{cases}$$

$\beta$ behaves like reflecting the real number line through the point $x=0$, except it also stretches the negative half and smushes the positive half. The important things about $\beta$ are

1 - $\beta( [-2a,a] ) = [-2a, a]$, i.e. all the sets in $A$ are invariant under $\beta$, and

2 - $\beta \circ \beta = id_{\mathbb R}$, i.e. it act like a symmetric reflection in that doing it twice brings you back to your original state.

Now we can use the fact that "the symmetry under $\beta$ extends to the generated $\sigma$ algebra" (proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778551/symmetric-sigma-algebra/4842511#4842511)), and get the result that all the sets in the $\sigma$ algebra generated by $A$ are invariant under $\beta$ as well. As a specific example, for the Borel set $[-2,2]$, $\beta( [-2,2] ) = [-1,4]$, and is thus not in $\sigma(A)$.

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm on the right path but f(x)=[-x,2x]?