# Symmetric $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{J}=\{(-a, a): a>0\}$. Show that $[0,1]\notin \sigma(\mathcal{J})$ and conclude that $\mathcal{J}$ is not a generator of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: The sets in $I$ have a property that is preserved by unions and intersections. It's pretty straightforward. Can you figure it out?

Comment: No. They're pretty special as far as intervals go. Suppose I told you that, say, 5/2 was in an interval from I. Could you tell me another point that must be in that same interval?

Comment: @JonathanZ Yes I messed that up... If $a=5/2$ then $(-5/2,5/2)\in\mathcal{J}$?! or is that not what you are getting it.

Comment: Yeah, they have a symmetry. Can you show that that symmetry is preserved by the sigma algebra operations? (I forgot to mention complements in my first comment!)

Comment: @JonathanZ I forgot to add that I did notice the fact that the interval is symmetric but I am having a hard time showing the preservation for countable unions and intersections. I assume the complement is preserved as $(-a, a)^c = (-\infty, -a] \cup [a, \infty)$.

Comment: By the way, when you move from the sets in $I$ to the sets in $\sigma(I)$, you'll get sets that are no longer intervals, like $(-3,3) \setminus (-2,2)$, so all you can say is that if 5/2 is in such a set, then -5/2 is also in the set. You can no longer assume they are intervals.

Comment: @JonathanZ I see it would be the union of two intervals of the form given in my comment. I got to admit that I am a tad bit more confused now on how to proceed and what suffices to show the point.

Comment: @learningsolo Assume all $X_i$ are symmetric and that $x\in \bigcup_i X_i.$ Show that $-x\in \bigcup_i X_i.$ Same for intersections. Similar for complements. Since symmetry is preserved by all the operations and holds on the generators, every set in $\sigma(\mathcal J)$ is symmetric, so $[0,1]\notin \sigma(\mathcal J)$

Comment: @learningsolo - spaceisdarkgreen is giving you the steps to take, if a bit tersely. Do they make sense to you, and do you see why they answer the question?

Comment: @JonathanZ Thank you and spaceisdarkgreen for your help and the follow up. I get that if symmetry is preserved by the $\sigma$-algebra operators, then it must follow since $[0,1]$ isn't symmetric. However, I do not see why this approach proves that the symmetry is preserved. I do not follow what $X_i$ is and why showing both $x,-x$ is somewhere in the operator set proves it. Is it related to the fact that there might be non-intervals?

Comment: @learningsolo "$X$ is symmetric" means "if $x\in X,$ then $-x\in X.$" So I'm just saying to show that if $X_i : i\in \mathbb N$ are all symmetric sets, then $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb M} X_i$ is symmetric, i.e. countable unions preserve symmetry. (But I'm also suggesting the logical steps to doing that: assume $x\in \bigcup_i X_i$ and then argue that $-x\in \bigcup_i X_i.$) On a side note, I guess you only need to do union and complement technically, as intersection can be defined in terms of them, but intersection isn't any harder than union: per the answer, it's all just unwinding definitions.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I get the idea now. Also yes by definition I only need union and complement. I just need to figure out how to show the symmetry for the two operators. Also, is it simply not Borel because all closed sets are Borel?

Comment: @learningsolo Yeah, specifically, $[0,1]\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ (since $[0,1]$ closed, or any other way you want to show that), so $\sigma(\mathcal J)$ can't be $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$

Comment: You're not asked to prove it, but I think you end up with all symmetric Borel sets.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen How would you show it for the complement? I can not make it make sense

Comment: @learningsolo Say $X$ is symmetric, i.e. for all $x\in \mathbb R,$ $x\in X\iff -x\in X.$ Then, by this and the definition of the complement, we have, for all $x\in \mathbb R,$ $$x\in X^c\iff x\notin X\iff -x\notin X\iff -x\in X^c.$$ Thus $X^c$ is symmetric.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you. I have shown it for the union as well. Now, could I simply say that since both operators of the sigma-algebra preserve the property of symmetry it follows that $[0,1]$ is not in the sigma algebra generated by $J$? Furthermore it is not equal to the Borel sigma-algebra because every closed set is a part of the Borel sigma-algebra?

Comment: @learningsolo Well, since the operators preserve symmetry, *and* the generators are all symmetric. As Jonathan mentioned, the easiest way to make this rigorous is to just note that the fact that the operations preserve symmetry means the collection of *all* symmetric sets is a $\sigma$-algebra (call it $\mathcal S$), and then note the definition of $\sigma(\mathcal J)$ implies that $\sigma(\mathcal J)\subseteq \mathcal S,$ since $\mathcal J\subseteq \mathcal S.$ (And as you say $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\not\subseteq \mathcal S$ since it contains $[0,1],$ which is not symmetric.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I finally get it this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Is it correct to say that $\mathcal{S}=\sigma(\{A\subset\mathbb{R}\mid A=-A\})$ is the collection of all symmetric sets?

Comment: @learningsolo Would be better to just say $\mathcal S := \{A\subseteq \mathbb R\mid  A = -A\}$ is the collection of all symmetric sets. (Though, since $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, as you've shown,  $\sigma(\mathcal S) = \mathcal S,$ so what you wrote down is technically correct.)

Comment: A small clarification in regards to " since the operators preserve symmetry, and the generators are all symmetric" and I promise this will be my last haha: Wouldn't we say that the operations perserve symmetry and because of that (*rather than only and*) the generators of $\sigma(\mathcal{J})$ are all symmetric?

Comment: @learningsolo No, the generators of $\sigma(\mathcal J)$ are the sets in $\mathcal J$ and the fact that they are symmetric has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that the operations preserve symmetry. Rather, it is just because $\mathcal J$ is a collection of manifestly symmetric sets, namely the intervals of the form $(-a,a).$

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the standard Borel algebra starts with a bunch of intervals, $\{(a,b) \mid a,b \in \mathbb R\}$, and ends up with sets like $\{5\}$ and $(3,7]$ and $[3,4) \cup (5,6]$. So we are going to step away from intervals and look for a weaker way to distinguish the sets in $\sigma(I)$.

Consider the map $x \mapsto -x$ on $\mathbb R$. We can apply it to subsets of $\mathbb R$, and say a set $A$ is "symmetric" if $A = -A$ or in other words, "if $x\in A$, then $-x \in A$". And we want to show that if $B\in \sigma(I)$ then $B$ is symmetric.

Intuitively, the sets we start with (i.e. $I$) are all symmetric. Now there are three things we can do to generate more sets in $\sigma(I)$:

- Take a countable collection of $A_i \in \sigma(I)$ and get $\cup_i A_i$.
- Take a countable collection of $A_i \in \sigma(I)$ and get $\cap_i A_i$.

or

- Take $A \in \sigma(I)$ and get $\mathbb R \setminus A$.

So you have to do the gritty work of showing that if all the sets you start with are symmetric, then in all three cases the set you get is also symmetric. It's basically just unwinding the definitions of union, intersection, and complement.

Once you've done that you're almost done, but the last step kind of depends on how you've defined the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a collection of subsets. If you've done it loosely - "just keep taking  unions and complements and intersections" - you're done.

If you've defined it rigorously, as the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras that contain your collection, then you can observe that $\{A\subset \mathbb R \mid A = -A\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and it contains $I$, so it will also contain $\sigma(I)$, and you'll be done.

Comment: Defining the $\sigma$-algebra as "just keep taking unions and complements and intersections" is really not a coherent definition without some serious machinery (e.g., ordinals), so instead of saying "then your done", I'd say "then you need to go back to the drawing board and pick a rigorous definition".

Comment: I added my definition of a $\sigma$-algebra and for the generator in a second.

Comment: @MW - Yeah, but based on the questions the OP is asking, I assumed they don't get to choose their definition, but have to work with the one their instructor provided. Me, I prefer to work with the rigorous definition, but it's not how people usually start off understanding it, and so I included the "loose definition" as an option in case that's how they're dealing with it

Comment: @JonathanZ I am not working with an instructor but rather myself. I am using "Measures Integrals and Martingales by René L. Schilling".

Comment: @JonathanZ I'd be sort of surprised at the level of talking about $\sigma$-algebras that classes and texts wouldn't be using rigorous definitions.  But I concede that you never know what's going on these days, so point taken.

Comment: @MW - Yeah, I'd never teach Analysis that casually, but now we see that the OP is a self-learner, and they might just want to get right on to Martingales. (Though why try to solve this problem then?) I just like to provide options for different levels of understanding.

Comment: @learningsolo - I see your definition of the sigma algebra generated by a collection. Have you covered the fact that you can explicitly "compute" it as the intersection of all sigma algebras containing your collection? I've used that fact in the rigorous version of the proof.

Comment: @learningsolo - okay then, you should try to understand the last paragraph. I admit it's a bit slapdash, and I've gotta go, but hopefully this gives you at least a bit more insight/understanding.

Comment: @JonathanZ Yes it uses $\mathcal{A}:=\bigcap_{\mathcal{F}\; \sigma\text{-algebra}, \;\mathcal{F\supset G}}^{}\mathcal{F}$

Comment: Nice. So one of those $\mathcal F$'s is "all symmetric sets".

Answer (score 0):

(I've already done one answer for this question, but that one's more of a "lead the OP to the answer" type of answer. The straight-forward solution to the OP's question, the one you might find in a text book, is so nice and general that I thought I'd add it as a separate answer. Plus, I'd like to refer to this answer in responding to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3866906/prove-that-a-does-not-generate-the-sigma-algebra-on-mathbbr).)

Let's generalize things a bit: Let $X$ be an arbitrary set, and $\alpha : X \rightarrow X$ be an *involution* defined on it, i.e. $\alpha \circ \alpha = id_X$. Notice that being an involution automatically makes $\alpha$ both onto and one-to-one.

We'll define $\mathcal F_\alpha = \{A \subset X \mid \alpha(A) = A\}$, i.e. the collection of all subsets of $X$ that are fixed by $\alpha$ - not point-wise fixed, but fixed when one takes the image of the entire set. You might want to think of $\mathcal F_\alpha$ as "all the sets that are symmetric under $\alpha$".

**Proposition 1:** $\mathcal F_\alpha$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Proof: i) $X$ is in $\mathcal F_\alpha$ by $\alpha$ being onto.

ii) For any function $f$, $f(\cup_{i \in I}A_i) = \cup_{i \in I}f(A_i)$ for arbitrary index sets $I$, not just countable ones. So if $A_i \in \mathcal F_\alpha, i = 1,2,3,...$ then

$$\alpha(\cup_{i}A_i) = \cup_{i}\alpha(A_i) = \cup_{i}A_i$$

so $\cup_{i}A_i \in \mathcal F_\alpha$.

iii) For any one-to-one function $f$, $f(X \setminus A) = f(X) \setminus f(A)$. So if $A \in \mathcal F_\alpha$, then

$$\alpha(X \setminus A) = \alpha(X) \setminus \alpha(A) = X \setminus A$$ so $X\setminus A \in \mathcal F_\alpha$. $\square$

**Proposition 2:** Whether we use the characterization of $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ as "the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal A$", or the "formula"

$$\sigma(\mathcal{A}) := \bigcap_{\mathcal{S}\; \sigma\text{-algebra}, \;\mathcal{S\supset A}}^{}\mathcal{S}$$

it's easy to see that i) $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal B \implies \sigma(\mathcal A) \subset \sigma(\mathcal B)$, and ii) if $\mathcal A$ is already a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\sigma(\mathcal A) = \mathcal A$. (Proof skipped.)

Jumping back to the OP's original question, recall that $\mathcal{J}=\{(-a, a): a>0\}$, and we'll let $A = \mathbb R$ and $\alpha(x) = -x$.

All the intervals in $\mathcal J$ are symmetric under $\alpha$, i.e. $\mathcal J \subset \mathcal F_\alpha$. By the above propositions, $\sigma(\mathcal J) \subset \sigma(\mathcal F_\alpha) = \mathcal F_\alpha$, or, putting it into words: "the symmetry under $\alpha$ extends to the generated $\sigma$ algebra". And since $[0,1]$ is not $\alpha$-symmetric it is not in $\sigma(\mathcal J)$, as we were asked to prove.

(Additional remark: Noting that the members of $\mathcal J$ are all intervals, and thus  trivially Borel sets, we also get that all the sets in $\sigma(\mathcal J)$ are Borel. I would love to prove the converse result, "$\sigma(\mathcal J)$ contains only $\alpha$-symmetric Borel sets", but have yet to find a proof of that.)